# How to write a list of integers to a binary file in python

Tags: python, performance, file, list

I have a list of integers which represent bytes of code. How can I write them to a binary file fast and more efficiently.

I have tried:

```
with open (output1, "wb") as compdata:
    for row in range(height):
        for data in cobs(delta_rows[row].getByte_List()):
            output_stream.append(Bits(uint=data, length=8))
    compdata.write(output_stream.tobytes())
```

and

```
with open (output1, "wb") as compdata:
    for row in range(height):
        bytelist = cobs(delta_rows[row].getByte_List())
        for byte in bytelist:
            compdata.write(chr(byte))
```

both get me a result which I think is correct (I have yet to reverse the process) but both take a long time (6min and 4min respectfully).

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Sorry Python 2 (2.7.5 specifically)

Comment: Have you looked at struct.Pack? That allows you to write binary data to strings (and to files). http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: first - only write once per {row, n rows, something} to get better performance. but does the stream.to_bytes() call clear it as well? otherwise, you are in exponential land... ex. you add [1,2,3]. you add [1] to output_stream, then write it. then you append 2, output_stream is now [1,2], and you write that. then you append 3, output_stream is now [1,2,3], and you write that.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Yeah I had indented it wrong when I wrote it down here on SE. Both segments of code output the exact same data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`bytearray()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray), write that straight to the output file:

```
with open (output1, "wb") as compdata:
    for row in range(height):
        bytes = bytearray(cobs(delta_rows[row].getByte_List()))
        compdata.write(bytes)
```

A sequence of integers is interpreted by a `bytearray()` as a sequence of byte values.

In Python 3, you can use a [`bytes()` type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) as well, with the same input; you are not mutating the values after creation, after all.

Comment: I have tried implementing this solution in my code and it also has a 4min implementation time. Its a good bit of code and is way better than using bitstring for this sort of thing.

Comment: At some point you'll have to figure out how much of that time is used by `cobs(delta_rows[row].getByte_List())`; the `bytesarray()` call takes the conversion of the result entirely into C code, so this is probably as fast as it is going to get.

Comment: It takes 0.111 sec to make that call multiplied by 2159 calls = 239 sec or 4min. You were right.