# Converting a text file containg numbers into binary format

Tags: python, io, binary

I have a python tools which only accepts binary files. As an input I have a csv file which in each line it contains one number. I just want to read the file and save a binary format from it.

I'm using following code, but final answer is broken.

```
import sys

def main(filename):
outfile = open('nums.bin','wb')
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
  outfile.write(bytes([ l.strip() for l in f.read().splitlines()]))
outfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1])
```

My input is in the following form:

```
102
111
54
.
```

The read function is as follow:

```
with open(datafile, 'rb') as file:
    bytes_in = bytearray(file.read())
    dataset = to_dataset(bytes_in, bits_per_symbol)
.
.
.

def to_dataset(bytes, bits_per_symbol):
    if bits_per_symbol <= 8:
        return list(bytes)
    elif bits_per_symbol <= 16:
        return [bytes[i]*256 + bytes[i+1] for i in range(0,len(bytes),2)]
    elif bits_per_symbol <= 24:
        return [bytes[i]*(256*256) + bytes[i+1]*256 + bytes[i+2] for i in range(0,len(bytes),3)]
    elif bits_per_symbol <= 32:
        return [bytes[i]*(256*256*256) + bytes[i+1]*(256*256) + bytes[i+2]*256 + bytes[i+3] for i in range(0,len(bytes),4)]
    else:
        return list()
```

which in function to_dataset, bits_per_symbol is defined by user and in my example is equal to 8.

I also look at below thread, but I couldn't figure out my answer for it:
[How to write a list of integers to a binary file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142491/how-to-write-a-list-of-integers-to-a-binary-file-in-python)

Comment: Whats the format of your binary file?

Comment: how come the binary format of 102 is 11001101101111? can you show the exact format the tools are expecting for 102, I think you are encontering the little/big endian trick

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import sys
import struct
def main(filename):
  outfile = open('nums.bin','wb')
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for l in f.read().splitlines():
                print struct.pack( 'i',int(l.strip()) )
                outfile.write( struct.pack( 'i', int( l.strip() )) )
  outfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: No it's not the things that I want. I want to save exact 102 into a file.  I mean I want to save 11001101101111.... into memory. Since in the other tools it's reading 8bit by 8bit and decode the value

Comment: how come the binary format of 102 is 11001101101111?  can you show the exact format the tools are expecting for 102, I think you are encontering  the little/big endian trick

Comment: I've concatenated first two number, I meant 102, 111, ... like:
0b1100110 + 0b1101111
I've edited the post which contains the read function too